# How can I upload separate 1X and 2X images?

Tags: assets, image, responsive-images

I want my site to serve 1X and 2X images depending on the browser using something like [Picturefill](http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/), and I don’t want the 1X version to just be automatically generated using a transform - I want to be able to upload separate 1X and 2X versions, and have them be linked together. How can I go about that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do that like so:

1. Create a new [Assets field](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/assets-fields) called “Hi-Res Image” (handle “`hiResImage`”) with the following settings:

   - **Restrict uploads to a single folder**: [ √ ]
   - **Upload Location**:

     - [same source you’re uploading 1X images to]
     - `{folder.path}_2x/`
   - **Restrict allowed file types**:

     - [ √ ]
     - [Images]
   - **Target Locale**: [Same as source]
   - **Limit**: 1
2. Go to Settings > Assets > [your source] > Fields tab, and add your new Hi-Res Image field to the layout.

With that set up, after you select 1X images in your main Assets field, you will be able to double-click on them and see your “Hi-Res Image” Assets field in their metadata modals. You can drag your 2X image into that, and it will automatically get saved into a _2x/ subfolder wherever its parent image lives.

From your templates, you can then output `<img>` tags that point to both images:

```twig
{% for image in entry.myAssetsField %}
    {% set hiResImage = image.hiResImage.first() %}

    <img srcset="{{ image.url }}
        {%- if hiResImage %}, {{ hiResImage.url }} 2x{% endif %}">
{% endfor %}
```